# how to get a string input from user with pre-defined string length in C++?

Tags: c++, string, string-length

I am trying to get a string with 8 characters long from the user.
User have to enter the string continuously. Once the string reaches 8 characters, it has to go next line of the code.

I've already tried with Arrays, and loops. But, It requires the user to hit enter after getting each character.

```
string str;
int b;
std::cin>>str.length(8);
```

Comment: Read one char at a time. Stop when you have 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done many different ways.

Try this

```
std::string str;
str.resize(8);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    std::cin >> str[i];
```

Or

```
std::string str;
str.resize(8);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    str[i] = std::cin.get();
```

Or

```
std::string str;
str.resize(8);
std::cin.read(&str[0], 8);
```

Or

```
char arr[9];
std::cin >> std::setw(9) >> arr;
std::string str(arr, 8);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in following way

```
char str[100], input;
int idx = 0;
while( scanf("%c", &input ) == 1 )  { 

    str[idx++] = input;
    if( idx >= 8 ) break; // or your desire length of string

}
```

Comment: Why are you recommending a C solution to a C++ question? `std::cin` has `get()` methods for reading single chars, and `read()` methods for reading char arrays.